# Powershell incrementing counter on variables

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to increment count on variable objects in Powershell?

Example:

```
$var1 = "This"
$var2 = "Is"
$var3 = "A Test"

1..3 | ForEach-Object {$var$_ = DoSometing}
```

Reason I am asking this, is because I am creating a GUI with `system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox`. I have several checkbox objects in variables that end with a number I want to manipulate.

```
$Checkbox1
$Checkbox2
$Checkbox3
$Checkbox4
```

I am wondering if there is a *clean* and good way to manipulate these objects with an `Foreach-Object`. Instead of manipulating each object seperatly.

Comment: What you're trying to do is ill-advised. Don't do it. Use an array instead: `$var = 1..3 | ForEach-Object { DoSomething }`.

Comment: Don't think `New-variable` will help much here. I think for your usecase, you could better loop over the Controls inside your Form object. eg: `$Form.Controls`. Simply loop over all controls and then check it by name, type or group.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to create variables, then this can be done with the `New-Variable` command.

```
Foreach ($z in (1..3)) {
    New-Variable -Name "Var$z" -Value $z
}

$var1,$var2,$var3
1
2
3
```

If you need to retrieve or update values for already existing variables, then similarly you can use `Get-Variable` and `Set-Variable`.

```
Foreach ($z in (1..3)) {
    Set-Variable -Name "Var$z" -Value "Updated $z"
    Get-Variable "Var$z" -ValueOnly
}

Updated 1
Updated 2
Updated 3
```

Comment: The variables are already created and contain data. I want to manipulate the data of variable 1 to 9 in a loop if this is possible. Alternatively I can manipulate the data the normal way, but this would create *a lot* of extra code and work when the script changes.